# Why CSS custom tag results in Angular error

Tags: html, css, angular

I've got the following scss

```
main{
    width: 100%;
    height: 840px;
    /*background: red;*/
    margin: 10px auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
section{
    width: 98%;
    height: 600px;      
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
....
```

and this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Simple responsive test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="text">
            <h1>Simple Test</h1>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam non atque adipisci est, recusandae aperiam, ullam minima quos nostrum animi voluptas sequi. At repellendus fuga reiciendis accusantium, dolor suscipit repellat?
            </p>
        </div>
        <section>
            <div class="product">
                <img src="image/banner2.png" alt="">
                <p>
                    <b>Product One</b><br>
                    <small>New arrival</small>
                </p>
                <samp>$45.00</samp>
            </div>
       </section>
   </main>
</body>
```

In vanilla HTML it works fine the browser recognize the tags and style accordingly

In Angular we get an error `main is not recognized` is there some action to be taken or Angular?

The error

> ```
> error NG8001: 'main' is not a known element:
> 1. If 'main' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'main' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
>
>                   <main>
>
>
> </main>
> ```

Comment: Where do you see this error ?

Comment: As Mihai asked - also curious as to where you see this error? Is this your IDE complaining or do you get compile errors? BTW - I doubt if it has anything to do with the scss..

Comment: @MihaiT - when I ng serve my project and in the browser my page doesn't load I've updated my question with the exact error received

Comment: check my answer below. Might do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to import your Component ( or the module that imports your Component ) inside the AppModule

Also, be sure to add **CommonModule** and **BrowserModule** in your AppModule. I think this is the issue.

So you would have something like

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    YourComponent,
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule
    // other modules you need
  ],
  .........
 })
 export class AppModule {
    }
```

**BUT** I would suggest you use a separate Module for your components and import that in your AppModule

**// conponents.module.ts ( or whatever name you want )**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { YourComponent}  from './YourComponent/your-component.component.ts';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule  ],
  declarations: [ YourComponent],
  exports:    [ YourComponent]
})
export class ComponentsModule{ }
```

**// app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { ComponentsModule } from './components/components.module.ts'

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, ComponentsModule  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I've tried adding `CommonModule` in both suggested ways (to `my-component`  |  `app.module` ) both result in the same error `main is not a known element`

Comment: @KukulaMula can you edit your question with your component.html and component.ts and maybe app.module.ts ?

Answer (score -2):

Your the class with `main` selector need a move to `./src/styles.scss` Or `./src/styles.css`.